# How to model one-to-many association in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to Sequelize, and I'm trying to figure out, how should I model one-to-many relationship.

My problem is as follows: one term, many papers.

```
var Term = sequelize.define( 'Term', ... );
var Paper = sequelize.define( 'Paper', ... );
```

Let's assume I have a term. Each term can have many papers, and I'd like to add/remove papers for my term. I'd also like to get all the papers for the term.

```
var term;
...
term.getPapers( ... );
term.setPapers( ... );
term.addPaper( paper );
term.removePaper( paper );
```

Now, let's assume I have a paper. I'd like to get/set the term for my paper.

```
var paper;

...

paper.getTerm();
paper.setTerm();
```

How can it be achieved using sequelize? I've been studying docs for hours, and also looking for some glues in the net, but without any results. I find this kind of association very poorly documented in sequelize (one-to-one and many-to-many are way better).

**Update**:

All right, several hours later I worked out how it works:

```
Term.hasMany( Paper, { as: 'papers' } );
Paper.hasOne( Term );
```

Now we can do:

```
term.addPaper( paper );
term.removePaper( paper );

paper.getTerm()
  .success( function( term )
  {
    ...
  });
paper.setTerm( term );
```

I've got used to Django, and it seems that Sequelize is FAR less mature, both in terms of code and documentation...

Comment: I agree, Sequelize's associations are extremely counter-intuitive to me and the documentation is not helping. Thank you for posting this.

Comment: Are you sure that `Paper.hasOne()` is a correct association type in this case? Shouldn't you use `Paper.belongsTo()`? That makes more sense according to the docs.

Comment: I disagree because I do not think one-to-one and many-to-many are better.. The documentation is so weird. It does not even explain the parameters and return values of methods created by associations. Thank you for posting this. :D (After some reading, now I think @SlavaFominII is probably right)

Answer (score 4):

First you have to create the association. You did it correctly:

```
  Term.hasMany( Paper, { as: 'papers' } );
  Paper.hasOne( Term );
```

Then you have to sync this declarations:

```
  sequelize.sync();
```

And now persist data. You need to save the objects before to associate it.

```
  term.create()...
  paper1.create()...
  paper2.create()...

  term.setPapers([paper1, paper2]).success(function() {
     // saved!
  })
```

Reference: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/docs/associations/#many-to-many-associations

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how you have structured the database, this would do thought..

```
paper.hasOne(term,{as:"PaperTerm"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that's great that you had figured out how it works but it would have been correct if you had used `Paper.belongsTo(Term);` instead of `Paper.hasOne( Term );`
Here is the [reference](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#implementation-2) if you'd like to read more about