# create Composite unique key including foreign key

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables `"Users"` and `"Applications"` such that a  user has multiple applications.
Now, I want to add a contraint that each user can have multiple but unique application names.

I have tried `unique: 'compositeIndex'` but it works with column only, not with foreign key column like `'userId'` in `'application'` Table.

```js
const createApplications = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const applications = sequelize.define('applications', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: 'compositeIndex'
        }
    });

    applications.associate = models => {
        applications.belongsTo(models.users, {
            delete: 'CASCADE',
            foreignKey: 'user_id',
            unique: 'compositeIndex'
        });
    }
    return applications;
};


const createUsers = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const users = sequelize.define('users', {
        eid: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    })
    return users;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing. It seems that you want a one to many mapping from `'User'` to `'Application'` table. If that's the case, have a look at this:
[one to many association in sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760994/how-to-model-one-to-many-association-in-sequelize)

Please edit your answer with expected result to clear what you want or add table structure screenshot.

Comment: The requerement is: 
if there are 3 applications A, B and C. and 2 users user1, user2.
then 
user1 ==> [A,B,C]
user2 ==> [A,B,C] (can have these applications

but not like
user1 ==> [A, B, A, C] (application should not be duplicated for one user)